# How to make PyPi description Markdown work?

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pypi

I uploaded a package to PyPi using:

```
python setup.py register -r pypi
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
```

I'm trying to modify the description, I wrote (**please don't edit the formatting of the following piece of code, I made it on purpose to demonstrate my problem**):

````
**my plugin**

This plugin enables you to ... For example:
```python
@attr(section='MySection', id=1)
def test_function(self):
    """
    Bla bla bla
    """
    pass
```
````

However, the text appears as it is, *without* the markdown formatting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

As of March 16, 2018, PyPI.org aka Warehouse (finally) supports Markdown in long descriptions. Warehouse replaced the old legacy PyPI implementation in April 2018.

You need to:

- Make sure [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) is upgraded to version 38.6.0 or newer
- Make sure [`twine`](https://pypi.org/project/twine/) is upgraded to version 1.11.0 or newer
- Make sure [`wheel`](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/) is upgraded to version 0.31.0 or newer
- Add a new field named `long_description_content_type` to your `setup()` call, and set it to `'text/markdown'`:

  ```
  setup(
      long_description="""# Markdown supported!\n\n* Cheer\n* Celebrate\n""",
      long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
      # ....
  )
  ```

  See [PEP 566 - *Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.1*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0566/#description-content-type-optional).
- Use `twine` to upload your distributions to PyPI:

  ```
  $ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel   # adjust as needed
  $ twine upload dist/*
  ```

The old legacy PyPI infrastructure would not render Markdown, only the new Warehouse infrastructure does. The legacy infrastructure is now gone (as of 2018-04-30).

Currently, PyPI uses [`cmarkgfm`](https://github.com/theacodes/cmarkgfm) as the markdown renderer, via the [`readme_renderer` library](https://github.com/pypa/readme_renderer) (using `readme_renderer.markdown.render(long_description)` to produce HTML output). This means that your markdown documents will render *exactly the same* as on GitHub; it is essentially the same renderer.

You can validate your package `long_description` with the [`twine check` command](https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/#validating-restructuredtext-markup) (`twine` 1.12.0 or newer).

The old < 2018-03-16 answer follows below.

---

> *Note: this is the old, now outdated answer, as of 2018-03-16 Markdown is supported provided you use the right tools, see above*.

PyPI does *not* support Markdown, so your README will not be rendered into HTML.

If you want a rendered README, stick with reStructuredText; the [Sphinx introduction to reStructuredText](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html) is a good starting point.

You probably want to install the [`docutils` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docutils) so you can test your document locally; you want to run the included `rst2html.py` script on your README to see what errors are produced, if any. Your specific sample has too many errors:

```
$ bin/rst2html.py test.rst  > /tmp/test.html
test.rst:7: (ERROR/3) Unexpected indentation.
test.rst:3: (WARNING/2) Inline literal start-string without end-string.
test.rst:3: (WARNING/2) Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
test.rst:11: (WARNING/2) Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
test.rst:11: (WARNING/2) Inline literal start-string without end-string.
test.rst:11: (WARNING/2) Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

Your code block is using Github's Markdown extensions, which are entirely wrong for reStructuredText. You could use a reST code block (probably, if the PyPI version of docutils is new enough):

```
.. code-block:: python

    @attr(section='MySection', type='functional+', module='MyModule', id=1)
    def test_function(self):
        """
        This is the original docstring
        """
        pass
```

To test this locally you'll need to install [Pygments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygments) as well.

There is a [feature request with pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/148) to add support for Markdown, if you are interested.

Answer (score 65):

As stated [in Martijn Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26737258), [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org) does not support Markdown.

Instead, convert the Markdown files into RestructuredText and upload those to PyPi.

One way to do this is to install [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and [PyPandoc](https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc), and then arrange to run them during packaging.

On OS X, Pandoc can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (`brew install pandoc`). Use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/) (`pip install pypandoc`) to install PyPandoc.

Then, modify `setup.py` like so:

```
try:
    import pypandoc
    long_description = pypandoc.convert_file('README.md', 'rst')
except(IOError, ImportError):
    long_description = open('README.md').read()

setup(
    name='blah',
    version=find_version('blah.py'),
    description='Short description',
    long_description=long_description,
)
```

Comment: Side question: Why also catch `IOError`? Is `ImportError` not the only expected exception in this case?

Comment: @NickChammas, I might be wrong but the ImportError might catch an exception when pypandoc can't be imported and the IOError might catch the possible case where `README.md` can't be opened or `README.rst` can't be written.

Comment: Thanks for this. One note: you need to include `README.md` as a data file in `setup.py` (`data_files=[('', ['README.md'])]`) otherwise you get an `RuntimeError` from pypandoc when installing with pip. Alternatively, the exception catch should be more general and feed long_description with a basic version instead.

Comment: `OSError` is raised when pandoc is not installed. I use `except (IOError, ImportError, OSError):`

Comment: `pypandoc.convert` has been depricated. Use `pypandoc.convert_file`

Comment: This answer needs an update: PyPi supports markdown nowadays.

Answer (score 13):

PyPI supports rst and not markdown as mentioned on other answers. But you don't need `pypandoc` perse, just `pandoc` is fine. You can generate the rst file locally first and then run setup.py to upload the package.

`upload.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
pandoc --from=markdown --to=rst --output=README README.md
python setup.py sdist upload
```

The generated file named `README` will be automatically recognized. Be sure to add it to your `.gitignore`! The `setup.py` doesn't have to do anything special.

`setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    packages=['mypackage'],  # this must be the same as the name above
    version='0.2.8',
    description='short',
    author='Chiel ten Brinke',
    author_email='<email>',
    url='<github url>',  # use the URL to the github repo
    keywords=[],  # arbitrary keywords
    classifiers=[],
)
```

Then just run `bash upload.sh` to upload the stuff to PyPI.

Comment: In my case the README file was not automatically recognized as long_description. One has to add the long_description field to setup.py . Otherwise the README file will not be rendered on pypi.

Answer (score 12):

You can set markdown in `setup.cfg` file too:

```
[metadata]
...
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
```

Checkout my project as an example: on [github](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/blob/b76e32725e4b8b4194eeedf8c2fbcf17c6fe0bc9/setup.cfg) and on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/).

Comment: Although `setup.py` *can* technically be cleverly jury-rigged to **(A)** safely open `README.md` with a context manager, **(B)** read the contents of that file into a local variable, and **(C)** set the `long_description` option to that variable's value outside of that context, **no one should actually do that.** `setup.cfg` already implements this correctly, safely, and efficiently on your behalf. Don't reinvent the rusty wheel. Just use `setup.cfg` for it is good. (*This has been a message from your friendly neighbourhood packager.*)

Comment: **Note:** this answer previously mixed the nonstandard `description-file` key specific to [pbr (Python Build Reasonableness)](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/features.html) with the standard `long-description-content-type` key *not* specific to pbr. I've since edited that erroneous discrepancy away by preferring the standard `long_description` and `long_description_content_type` keys. This answer now behaves as expected for everyone – regardless of whether you're using pbr or not. All is now right with the packaging world.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 4):

I've had issues with `\r` characters causing parsing issues where only the first line of the README appears in pypi. The code below fixes the issue, it comes from the `pypandoc` module repository:

```
try:
    long_description = pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst')
    long_description = long_description.replace("\r","") # Do not forget this line
except OSError:
    print("Pandoc not found. Long_description conversion failure.")
    import io
    # pandoc is not installed, fallback to using raw contents
    with io.open('README.md', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        long_description = f.read()
```

This way `long_description` contains a sanitized version of your Readme and you can pass it to the setup() function in your `setup.py` script.

Comment: Got downvoted, haven't tried this in a while so if this does not work please report it

Comment: Worked for me, thank you so much! I've spent hours troubleshooting. ... Why `io.open` instead of just `open`?

Comment: Downvote may have been because `convert_text` requires `format=md` argument while `convert_file` does not. I'm not sure what mechanism bare `convert` uses. Maybe particular situations also require the argument. c.f. https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc/blob/master/README.md#usage

Comment: Those two functions must be new additions to pypandoc because they did not exist before. Are you saying this code using bare `convert` does not work ?

Comment: Bare convert didn't work for me on one machine, but did on another. I didn't investigate to see what was different between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I found the other answers here sort of complicated.

To get my github page `readme.md` file to show on my PyPi page, I followed the following two steps in my `setup.py` file.

#### 1. Include the following at the top of my `setup.py` file

```
from pathlib import Path
this_directory = Path(__file__).parent
long_description = (this_directory / "readme.md").read_text()
```

These steps directly read in the data from your markdown file into the `long_description` variable.

#### 2. Input the following parameters to the `setup()` function

```
long_description = long_description
long_description_content_type="text/markdown"
```

This inserts the data from your markdown file into `long_description`, and then tells `setup()` what type of data it is (markdown).

As I said, the above two steps worked great on my first try, without any hassles or complexity. Perfect for my little brain. :)

Note this code is adapted from:
https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/

Answer (score 2):

There is a good pip package that worked for me

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/restructuredtext_lint/

I'm using it on my setup now:

https://github.com/pablodav/burp_server_reports/blob/master/setup.py

```
def check_readme(file='README.rst'):
"""
Checks readme rst file, to ensure it will upload to pypi and be formatted correctly.
:param file:
:return:
"""
errors = rst_lint.lint_file(file)
if errors:
    msg = 'There are errors in {}, errors \n {}'.format(file, errors[0].message)
    raise SystemExit(msg)
else:
    msg = 'No errors in {}'.format(file)
print(msg)
```

Also I have created a lib to be able to use in py.test later

```
https://github.com/pablodav/burp_server_reports/blob/master/burp_reports/lib/check_readme.py
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 Update:

No need for a `setup.py` file.
Under your poetry.toml file or simply your .toml file, there is a [tool.poetry] section, under that you put readme = "README.md". Example:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "Example Module"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Module Description"
readme = "README.md"
authors = ["Author Name <author_email@email.com>"]
```